# Definitions of well ordered set, maximal element and upper bound

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am currently studying equivalents of the Axiom of choice such as the well ordering theorem and the Zorn's lemma. I understand partially and linearly ordered set is a primitive definition in both definitions.

So this are the definitons i have got so far:

A  partial ordering on a non-empty set $S$ is a binary relation $R$ such that for all  $ a, b , c \in S$ satisfies:

1. $R$ is reflexive, i.e.,  $aRa$.
2. $R$ is antisymmetric, i.e.,  if $aRb$ and $bRa$ then $ a = b $.
3. $R$ is transitive, i.e., if $aRb$ and $bRc$ then $aRc$.

A partially ordered set, $(S,R)$ is a linear ordered set or a  totally ordered set if any two elements in $S $ is comparable

A linearly ordered set $(S,\leq)$ is a well ordered set, if for every $A \subseteq S$, there exists an element $s_0$ where $s_0 < s \forall s \in T$.
From my understanding when we consider a partially ordered set or a linealy ordered set the relation it's defined under can be any binary relation such as addition, subset etc. However, when considering a well ordered set we only consider the partially ordered set (S,<), i.e. the set under the less than ordering.

This is also the case when we look at upper bound and maximal element. The partially ordered set we consider is the set defiend under the less than relation

Is this right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [PO set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set): "A partially ordered set formalizes and generalizes the intuitive concept of an ordering or arrangement of the elements of a set. A poset consists of a set together with a binary relation indicating that, for certain pairs of elements in the set, one of the elements precedes the other in the ordering. **The word partial is used as an indication that not every pair of elements needs to be comparable**. That is, there may be pairs of elements for which neither element precedes the other."

Comment: [Total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order): "A total order is a binary relation on some set which is antisymmetric, transitive, and a connex relation. The connex property means that any pair of elements in the set of the relation are comparable under the relation. A set paired with a total order is called a chain."

Comment: [Well-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order): "A well-order on a set S is a total order on S with the property that every non-empty subset of S has a least element in this ordering."

Comment: "when we consider a partially ordered set or a linealy ordered set the relation it's defined under can be any binary relation such as addition, subset etc." ??? With numbers, the "usual" $\le$ is a partial order. With subsets of a given set, inclusion is.

Comment: "Addition" is not a binary relation: it is a binary operation that for each input pair of numbers outputs a number. (It can be expressed with a *ternary* relation.)

Comment: I agree: @Elise, you appear to be confused in a way I can't diagnose from your question. Could you write out the difference between "$\mathbb{N}$" and "$\mathbb{N}$ well-ordered", so that the difference of your second paragraph becomes clear?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So a partially ordered set can only ever be under 2 relations which are $\leq$ and $\subseteq$ ?

Comment: @PatrickStevens I have now edited my orginal post and included the definitions i am using so far. What i am confused with is when i am describing a well ordered set, does the partially ordered set needs to be $(S,\leq)$ or can it be any $(S,R)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to believe that $\le$ has some specific meaning - perhaps you're thinking that $a \le b$ if and only if $b - a$ is nonnegative, for example.

On the contrary, $\le$ is used as a symbol to indicate *any* relation that is intended to be interpreted as some kind of ordering. The meaning of $\le$ will be defined before it is used. It need not be a relation on $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{R}$; I could define the relation-class $\le$ on the class of all sets by $X \le Y$ if and only if $X$ injects into $Y$, for example. Or I could define $\le$ on the genuine set $\{\text{the ordinals less than $\alpha$}\}$ by $\beta \le \gamma$ iff $\beta$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $\gamma$.